# After asset expiration time reached, it is not getting unpublished

Tags: adobe, aem, aem-6

AEM provides OOTB functionality to automatically unpublish asset when it reaches expiration time. Fortunately, it is working in my local environment, however on Staging it is not working. 
I have tried changing the Cron expression in conf "Adobe CQ DAM Expiry Notification", but no luck.
Is there any configuration that I am missing ?
Please suggest

Comment: an errors in the logs? Is the workflow executed at all?

Comment: no workflow didn't activate.

Comment: Did you find the root cause? You can create a logger for this workflow and adjust the log level to debug to get more info.